# How can I get a message by the ID?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
bot=discord.Client()


@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    idbot = 835947059721797702
    if ctx.author.id == idbot:
        print(ctx.content)
        channelsnipe = bot.get_channel(833472112290168842)
        id = await client.get_message(channelsnipe,idbot)

        #await asyncio.sleep(0.2) # Give time for reaction to update on cache
        #reaction = id.reactions[0] # Get first reaction of a message
        #emoji = reaction.emoji
        #await id.add_reaction(emoji)
```

I'm trying to get a message by the ID that a bot send to me and after i wanna add a reaction to this message but I tried to get the message by `fetch_message` and `get_message` but no one worked. I always have this error `module 'discord.client' has no attribute 'get_message'`

Answer (score 0):

[`TextChannel`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v1.7.2/discord/channel.py#L53), [`DMChannel`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v1.7.2/discord/channel.py#L1179), [`GroupChannel`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v1.7.2/discord/channel.py#L1288) objects implement the `Messageable` protocol.

There [`fetch_message`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v1.7.2/discord/abc.py#L1104) method is implemented.

So use

```py
message = await channelsnipe.fetch_message(idbot)
```

Comment: ```AttributeError: module 'discord.client' has no attribute 'get_message'``` : its doesnt work :c

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you running?

Comment: I made a typo in my answer :D. It should be fetch_message

Comment: i got this : ```discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 20002): Only bots can use this endpoint```

Comment: How are you authenticating? Using the Bot token or OAuth2?

Comment: its for a selfbot

Comment: I recommend setting up an actual bot account as discord doesn't allow self-bots to perform this operation https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

Answer (score 0):

try it

```py
message = await channelsnipe.fetch_message(idbot)
```

Comment: its doesnt work ==> ```discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 20002): Only bots can use this endpoint```